# Can't log into my Blogger account

Tags: blogger, account-recovery

I haven't been able to log into my Blogger account for my blog or into the Gmail of the same account. I remember the recovery mail that I'd connected and I've tried using the account recovery several times and it won't email me anything. My blog was also on private so I can't access any of my old posts. Please can someone help or does anyone have any contact details that I could use to get in touch with Google/Blogger support? I really want my account back.

Answer (score -1):

A fix that worked for me, was to do the following:

1. Go to accounts.google.com;
2. Go to *Data & personalisation*;
3. Scroll downward until you find *Things you create and do*, and subsequently click on *Google Dashboard*;
4. Under *Your Google services*, click on *Blogger*;
5. **DON'T** click on *Go to Blogger*, rather, click on *1 profile entry* if it appears (you may need to expand the tile) and once followed it should prompt you to add a new username.